# Maximizing HDD space on dual boot Fedora 16 and Ubuntu 12.04 system

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, gparted, fedora

My question is very specific.  In the screenshot here of my GParted, you can see Fedora 16 installed on /dev/sda4 and Ubuntu (with the mount point "/") on /dev/sda6.  Partition /dev/sda5 is taking up 48 GiB of space and there seems to be nothing on it but a lost+found folder.  I want to remove this partition and expand both my Fedora and Ubuntu partitions to use the resulting unallocated space.  This is a fresh install of both operatng systems and there is no data on the computer to lose.  Is it safe to remove the /dev/sda5 partition and resize the other two using GParted from a live CD?

[image: GParted Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one had an answer, I went ahead and tried it out.  I was warned that moving and Resizing my boot partition my result in problems, but forged ahead anyway.  I deleted the /dev/sda5 partition and resized both my Fedora and Ubuntu partitions, all using GParted on my Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD, and everything went fine.  I just figured I would close this out just in case anyone else has the same question I did.